# Pandoc lua filters, turn sections into unnumbered ones

Tags: templates, lua, markdown, pandoc

I am developing a pandoc markdown template for a journal whose final format needs sections to be unnumbered, that is, \section and children should become \section*.

I know that is sufficient to add {-} in the markdown next to the header title, but I want to force this behaviour and do not depend on users writing markdown correctly.

I tried with:

```
function Header(el)
  el.classes = 'unnumbered'
  return el
end
```

but it makes the headers disappear... I am totally new to LUA so bear with me.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Success!

I needed curly brackets around the class to denote a "table"

```
function Header(el)
  el.classes = {'unnumbered'} -- curly brackets were missing here
  return el
end
```

or use an index since classes is a List:

```
function Header(el)
  el.classes[1] = 'unnumbered' -- classes is a List
  return el
end
```

Comment: I'd output classes or have a look at the docs to ensure that you're overwriting no classes here (or only overwriting the classes you actually wanted to overwrite if there's some "numbered" class). Otherwise, you should be using `table.insert` to add a class, or linearly searching through the classes to replace a class by index.

Comment: could you post a code example so that I can mark yours as correct answer?

Comment: Basically just `table.insert(el.classes, 'unnumbered')` should there be no need to override classes; otherwise something like `for i, v in ipairs(el.classes) do if v == "class_to_be_replaced" then el.classes[i] = 'unnumbered' end end`. Perhaps better suited as an edit to your answer.

Comment: Some syntax sugar that works for these lists: `el.classes:insert('unnumbered')`.

Comment: thanks to both of you!