# Adding classes to headers with a Pandoc lua filter

Tags: templates, lua, markdown, pandoc

I'm putting together a Quarto template for Springer Nature journals. [The LaTeX document class](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support#c17590862) has some frustrating aspects that I'm trying to circumvent with lua filters so the template can be used as much as possible with vanilla markdown. One such filter (inspired by [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284412/pandoc-lua-filters-turn-sections-into-unnumbered-ones)) takes any heading with the class `{.backmatter}` and for the PDF format, uses `\bmhead*` instead of `\section`; this bit works as expected:

```lua
local backmatter_inserted = false

function Header(el)
  if quarto.doc.isFormat("pdf") then
    if not backmatter_inserted and el.classes:includes("backmatter") then
      backmatter_inserted = true
      el.content = pandoc.utils.stringify(el.content)
      return {
        pandoc.RawBlock('tex', '\\backmatter'),
        pandoc.RawBlock('tex', '\\bmhead*{' .. el.content .. '}')
      }
    elseif el.classes:includes("backmatter") then
      el.content = pandoc.utils.stringify(el.content)
      return pandoc.RawBlock('tex', '\\bmhead*{' .. el.content .. '}')
    end
  elseif quarto.doc.isFormat("html") and el.classes:includes("backmatter") then
    el.classes:insert("appendix")
    el.classes:insert("unnumbered")
    return el
  end
end
```

However, the HTML portion of the filter does not appear to be working as intended. For the HTML output, I'd like to tuck content under these headings away unnumbered in the appendix, e.g. by adding the classes "appendix" and "unnumbered". Neither of these classes currently appear to be added when running this filter.

I tried adding the classes in the md input and it works as expected, with the heading appearing in the appendix unnumbered:

```markdown
# Heading {.backmatter .unnumbered .appendix}
Sample text
```

Running pandoc native, this appears as:

```
Header
    3
    ( "heading" , [ "backmatter" , "unnumbered" , "appendix" ] , [] )
    [ Str "Heading" ]
```

With only `{.backmatter}` as an input class and running the filter, it appears as:

```
Header
    3
    ( "heading" , [ "backmatter" ] , [] )
    [ Str "Heading" ]
```

I've read somewhere about a change in handling of Pandoc for section classes: am I missing something here?

Comment: did you solve your problem meanwhile? It seems you are not handling "native" format in this lua function, so it does not make changes to element el.